# MySQL Query to get the SUM of Products Sold per Week using join to get average data from another table

Tags: mysql, sql

```
select week(cd.date_time,4) as week, year(cd.date_time) as year, p.product_name as product_name, p.asin as asin, 
round(avg(cd.bsr_lv1)) as bsr_lv1, round(avg(cd.bsr_lv2)) as bsr_lv2, cd.stock_status as stock_status, COALESCE(NULLIF(round(avg(cd.price)),''),NULLIF(round(avg(cd.sale_price)),'' ),NULLIF(round(avg(cd.deal_price)),''), 'OOS') as price, round(avg(cd.review_total)) as reviews, round(avg(cd.rating),1) as rating,
(case when (round(sum(sr.unit_sold)) in ('','N/A',NULL)) THEN 0 ELSE round(sum(sr.unit_sold)) END) as unit_sold 
from crawl_data cd 
left join products p on p.id=cd.product_id 
left join sale_report sr on sr.product_id=cd.product_id 
where (date(cd.date_time) BETWEEN CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL '6' WEEK AND CURRENT_DATE) and 
p.asin='B07H66KQ1B' and week(cd.date_time,4)=week(sr.date_time,4) 
group by week(cd.date_time,4), year(cd.date_time)
```

The above query producing a wrong sum of unit_sold.

Anyone here who can help me with me query? I will be very thankful.

Comment: If you're still struggling, see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Please provide sample data, desired results, and an explanation of "wrong sum of unit_sold".

Comment: You could probably replace `(case when (round(sum(sr.unit_sold)) in ('','N/A',NULL)) THEN 0 ELSE round(sum(sr.unit_sold))` with `round(coalesce(sum(sr.unit_sold), 0))

Comment: Hi Gorden, This query below returns perfect result.:- select week(date_time,4), sum(unit_sold) from sale_report
where asin='B07H66KQ1B'
group by week(date_time,4)

Comment: result of the above query 41  0
42  3
43  5
44  18
45  14
46  6
47  8
48  4

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies in the case statement.

```
(case when (round(sum(sr.unit_sold)) in ('','N/A',NULL)) THEN 0 ELSE round(sum(sr.unit_sold)) END) as unit_sold.
```

Round and sum should be the outermost functions. Case statement should check individual column, not summed up and rounded column.

Comment: Thanks for comment. I have tried with sum(sr.unit_sold) as unit_sold, but still its returning wrong sum.

Answer (score -1):

This is your query:

```
select week(cd.date_time, 4) as week,
       year(cd.date_time) as year,
       p.product_name as product_name,
       p.asin as asin, 
       round(avg(cd.bsr_lv1)) as bsr_lv1,
       round(avg(cd.bsr_lv2)) as bsr_lv2,
       cd.stock_status as stock_status, 
       coalesce(nullif(round(avg(cd.price)), ''),  
                nullif(round(avg(cd.sale_price)), '' ),  
                nullif(round(avg(cd.deal_price)), ''),
                'OOS'
               ) as price,
       round(avg(cd.review_total)) as reviews, 
       round(avg(cd.rating), 1) as rating,
       (case when (round(sum(sr.unit_sold)) in ('', 'N/A', NULL)) then 0 else round(sum(sr.unit_sold)) end) as unit_sold 
from crawl_data cd left join
     products p
     on p.id = cd.product_id left join
     sale_report sr
     on sr.product_id = cd.product_id 
where date(cd.date_time) BETWEEN CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL '6' WEEK AND CURRENT_DATE and 
      p.asin = 'B07H66KQ1B' and 
      week(cd.date_time, 4) = week(sr.date_time, 4) 
group by week(cd.date_time, 4), year(cd.date_time);
```

It has a few issues:

- The `left join` to products is not needed.  It is turned into an inner join by the `WHERE` clause.
- Multiple columns are in the `select` that are not in the `group by` . . . such as `product_name`, `asin`, and `stock_status`.
- The calculation of `price` just makes no sense, because it is combining numbers and strings.
- The calculation of `units_sold` makes no sense, because it is comparing the output of a numeric function to strings.
- `IN (. . . NULL)` is useless.  It will never return `true`.

Given all these issues and no real explanation, I can only speculate on what a useful query would be.  The following is my best guess:

```
select week(cd.date_time, 4) as week,
       year(cd.date_time) as year,
       p.product_name as product_name,
       p.asin as asin, 
       round(avg(cd.bsr_lv1)) as bsr_lv1,
       round(avg(cd.bsr_lv2)) as bsr_lv2,
       cd.stock_status as stock_status, 
       coalesce(nullif(round(avg(cd.price)), 0),  
                nullif(round(avg(cd.sale_price)), 0),  
                nullif(round(avg(cd.deal_price)),
               ) as price,  -- just return `NULL` if there is no price
       round(avg(cd.review_total)) as reviews, 
       round(avg(cd.rating), 1) as rating,
       round(sum(case when sr.unit_sold in ('', 'N/A') then 0 else 0 + sr.unit_sold end), 1) as unit_sold  -- is units_sold really a string???
from crawl_data cd join
     products p
     on p.id = cd.product_id left join  -- this could probably be an inner join as well
     sale_report sr
     on sr.product_id = cd.product_id 
where date(cd.date_time) BETWEEN CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL '6' WEEK AND CURRENT_DATE and 
      p.asin = 'B07H66KQ1B' and 
      week(cd.date_time, 4) = week(sr.date_time, 4) 
group by week(cd.date_time, 4), year(cd.date_time),
         p.product_name, p.asin, cd.stock_status;
```

Comment: Hi Gordon, Thanks so much for your valuable comment. The query you mentioned produces exactly the same result as mine. No differences at all.